# ngx-charts can I set the y axis increment

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I have a data set with whole number values less than 5. The ngx-charts y axis shows tick marks at 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, etc. Is there a way to make it only put tick marks at whole number increments?

Answer (score 1):

In the [doc](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/normalized-vertical-bar-chart), they talking about an Input property for ***normalized chart*** :
**yAxisTicks** of type **any[]**
so you can pass an array of number value for exemple :

```
<ngx-charts-area-chart-normalized
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [legend]="legend"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxis]="xAxis"
  [yAxis]="yAxis"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  [yAxisTicks]= [0,2000,555550000,650000000]
  [timeline]="timeline"
  [results]="multi"
  (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-area-chart-normalized>
```

Comment: Hi, I want my Y axis to start from min 5 and no max value...I used [yScaleMin] = "5" then it decreased from 5 to 0 up the scale. ONce I define both [yScaleMin] = "5"
  [yScaleMax] = "50" its going 5 to 50, but can I exclude the max value or override the transform function?

Answer (score 1):

add [yScaleMin]="yScaleMin" [yScaleMax]="yScaleMax"

and in component
yScaleMin = 0
yScaleMax = 5